# continue editing when emulator or device is testing code

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8-emulator

Apologies if this has already been asked or not doable, but when I code in IOS or Eclipse I can make code changes even if the app is running on my device while testing some aspect.  I then just rebuild and it restarts the app on the device with the modified code.

Is there a way I can do the same with Visual Studio 2012?  It is very annoying if I forget to stop the device from testing the app and try type in code only to be prevented from making changes.  Not a show stopper I know, but if there is a setting some where it sure would be helpful.

So in a nutshell, I want to run some code on my device (lumia 520), note an issue, make the change in MainPage.xzml.cs or elsewhere and then just restart the build and it will stop the app running on the device and restart it with the modified code.

I will keep looking myself but as it always the case, sometimes its harder to find the right question to ask than get to the answer.  Hope the question makes sense and appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Seems as its a default way Visual Studio works as I get the same issue with Visual Studio 2013.  Could not find anything in OPTIONS so will leave it at that.